# Использование JSON в Django

Tags: json, javascript, django

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть вьюха, из которой мне нужно передать JSON объект.

делал так:

```
return render_to_response("catalog/item.htm", {'json_obj': json.dumps(images)})
```

но если я просто пробую вставить

```
{{json_obj}}
```

в код на javascript, то это не срабатывает. 
Видимо джанговский шаблонизатор не дает встраивать переменные в скрипты, потому что просто в html эта строка выводится корректно.
Подскажите как нужно передавать объект JSON в JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рабочий пример

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps({"success": True}), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Да, такое у меня получалось. Я не могу понять как сделать чтобы в return рендерилися нужный мне шаблон, и при этом JSON строка передавалась в JavaScript.

Comment: var a = "{{ json_obj|escapejs }}";